# R ggbiplot - How to change the axes scales according to length of loadings?

Tags: r, pca, ggbiplot

I performed a PCA analysis (on Iris data) using the R prcomp package.
When I am plotting the results using the ggbiplot function, the scale of the axes is according to the rotated data (= ir_pca$x) (see picture link below), but I want the axes scales according to the loadings (= ir_pca$rotation) as well.
Two plots would be nice. One with the loadings and the corresponding axes scaling and one extra plot displaying only the rotated data and its corresponding axes scales.
A third option would be to display both scales in one plot, i.e., rotated data on the bottom and left side and the loadings scales on the topmost and right side.

```
ir_pca <- prcomp(ir, center=TRUE, scale=TRUE)

g = ggbiplot(
        ir_pca,
        choices=c(1, 2),
        groups=iris[, 5],
        var.axes=TRUE,
        obs.scale=1,
        ellipse=TRUE
)
```

print(g)

[Result of the PCA (Iris data) analysis displaying only the rotated data on the scaling axes.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O2nt.png)